# How to filter data from vertical to horizontal, with a field as unique key in Linux

Tags: linux, filter

I have blocks of data, each of which starts with `<SUBBEGIN`, and ends with `<SUBEND`. My content is like this:

```
<SUBBEGIN
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER=803838478;
PAIDTYPE=0;
SUBSCRIPTION=TOOMUCH&73337E0380B4B30F&1&AAA&BBB&CCC&1&1&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&255&1&255&256&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&0&0&128&1&255&255&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&0&0&0&1&0&0&1;
SUBSCRIPTION=TASKS&E7CC601262AB3535&1&DDD&EEE&FFF&2&1&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&255&0&255&256&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&0&0&128&1&255&255&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&0&21&0&1&0&0&1;
<SUBEND
<SUBBEGIN
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER=705959905;
PAIDTYPE=254;
SUBSCRIPTION=REALLY&73337E0380B4B30F&1&GGG&HHH&LLL&1&1&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&255&1&255&256&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&0&0&128&1&255&255&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&0&0&0&1&0&0&1;
SUBSCRIPTION=TIRED&E7CC601262AB3535&1&MMM&NNN&PPP&2&1&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&255&0&255&256&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&0&0&128&1&255&255&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&0&21&0&1&0&0&1;
<SUBEND
```

I plan to make the horizontal version and using some fields only, the Header plan for the result is like this:

```
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER,,,PAIDTYPE,,1,255,SERVICENAME,SUBSCRIBEDATETIME,VALIDFROMDATETIME,EXPIREDDATETIME,,,,,
```

From that data:

```
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER sample is 803838478 (we can see it in SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER)
PAIDTYPE sample is 0 (we can see it in PAIDTYPE)
SERVICENAME sample is TOOMUCH (we can see it in SUBSCRIPTION)
SUBSCRIBEDATETIME sample is AAA (we can see it in SUBSCRIPTION)
VALIDFROMDATETIME sample is BBB (we can see it in SUBSCRIPTION)
EXPIREDDATETIME sample is CCC (we can see it in SUBSCRIPTION)
```

So the expected result is like this:

```
803838478,,,0,,1,255,TOOMUCH,AAA,BBB,CCC,,,,,
803838478,,,0,,1,255,TASKS,DDD,EEE,FFF,,,,,
705959905,,,254,,1,255,REALLY,GGG,HHH,LLL,,,,,
705959905,,,254,,1,255,TIRED,MMM,NNN,PPP,,,,,
```

I tried this script:

```
awk -F"&" '/^<SUBBEGIN$/{a=1} a && /^[[:blank:]]+(SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|PAIDTYPE|SUBSCRIPTION)/{l=l OFS $1} a && /^<SUBEND$/ {print l; a=l=""}' sample.txt
```

but the result is not as expected:

```
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER=803838478;         PAIDTYPE=0;         SUBSCRIPTION=TOOMUCH         SUBSCRIPTION=TASKS
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER=705959905;         PAIDTYPE=254;         SUBSCRIPTION=REALLY         SUBSCRIPTION=TIRED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'[=;&]' -v OFS=',' '
    /<SUBBEGIN/,/<SUBEND/{
        if($1 == "SUBSCRIPTION"){
            i++
            a["SUBSCRIPTIONS"]=i
            a["SERVICENAME"i]=$2
            a["SUBSCRIBEDATETIME"i]=$5
            a["VALIDFROMDATETIME"i]=$6
            a["EXPIREDDATETIME"i]=$7
        }else{
            a[$1]=$2
        }
    }
    /<SUBEND/{
        for(i=1; i<=a["SUBSCRIPTIONS"]; i++){
            print ( \
                    a["SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER"], 
                    "","",
                    a["PAIDTYPE"],
                    "",1,255,
                    a["SERVICENAME"i],
                    a["SUBSCRIBEDATETIME"i],
                    a["VALIDFROMDATETIME"i],
                    a["EXPIREDDATETIME"i],
                    "","","","","" \
                )
        }
        i=0
     }
' file

803838478,,,0,,1,255,TOOMUCH,AAA,BBB,CCC,,,,,
803838478,,,0,,1,255,TASKS,DDD,EEE,FFF,,,,,
705959905,,,254,,1,255,REALLY,GGG,HHH,LLL,,,,,
705959905,,,254,,1,255,TIRED,MMM,NNN,PPP,,,,,
```